# How to solve: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file?

Tags: syslog, aptdaemon

Since i installed 19.04 I start to getting this error in my syslog sent from gdm-session-wor:

```
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I've been trying to find a solution for this problem. See these bug reports I submitted in an attempt to do so. If you can confirm that you are using ZSH, that would be worth adding to the bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1849081 https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/8296 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/280 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1817128 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1818616 https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/issues/28

Comment: I'm getting this on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Answer (score 4):

This is an informational message; it's not an issue.

You can see [this Arch Linux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=261156) for details

> It doesn't find the daemon control file, so it caches the password, and is successful in opening the keyring once the session is properly initialized.
>
> Read, there is no issue and no error and this is of informational value. It could be relevant if the daemon fails to start during session init, as that isn't the case here it can be safely ignored.
>
> The underlying reason is likely that gkr-pam runs before the system  gets around to initializing the rest of the session and starting relevant user services, so the gnome-keyring daemon that is intended to be unlocked does not yet run the first time this check happens.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this message you can edit this file:

/etc/pam.d/gdm-password

`only_if=gdm` in the following line should do the trick ...

`auth   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so only_if=gdm`

Without `only_if=gdm` I got this "issue" and fake unlocked keyring from
systemctlt status gdm3.service

I dont know why ...

Comment: I found necessary to edit this line too:
original: "session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start"
new: "session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so only_if=gdm"