# 22.04 - GDM Shell crashes (occasionally) after login

Tags: gnome, 22.04, login, crash, gdm

How would I diagnose a GDM crash after login.  I can still SSH into the machine and I've been "fixing" broken shell session with:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop gdm
$ sudo systemctl start gdm
```

What logs would I need to look at to begin diagnosis?

Comment: You need to check the output of `journalctl -rxu gdm`

Comment: Found this in the output: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file. Trying this fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144153/how-to-solve-gkr-pam-unable-to-locate-daemon-control-file

Comment: @Raffa This is the only output: GLib: Source ID 203 was not found when attempting to remove it

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it - going to try a different greeter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved.

I installed lightdm as the greeter and am using that. Note, I am **not** installing UNITY, but rather just the lightdm for the role of entering the password and logging into the GNOME shell GUI which remains unaltered.

I also needed to make sure that lightdm didn't put the machine to sleep when logged out and or "Switch Users" was chosen.  To accomplish this, I followed the following post: [How to disable suspend in 20 minutes from the lightdm login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337649/how-to-disable-suspend-in-20-minutes-from-the-lightdm-login-screen)

This has solved my issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, AMD RYZEN Threadripper and an NVIDIA RTX4090 using the propreitary 530 driver.