Ubuntu 23.10 login loop occurs on raspberry Pi 5 Gnome 45.2
I am trying to log in using corect uid and password but it loops and always come back to the authentication black screen.
Ctrl+alt+F2 using the exact same uid+pwd  works well.
It happened just after I did install KDE PLASMA using Application Center tool.
Any idea ?

Have you tried checking the output of /var/log/auth.log?

No...But just did it....Then: gdm-password ]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file.  gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in opened session

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144153/how-to-solve-gkr-pam-unable-to-locate-daemon-control-file i don't think that's an error just info

Well..  Looking closely at the informations included in this file I can see that my attemp to log in immediately after that using Ctrl+Alt+F2 is successfull.  So there is no more "informations / lines " between those 2 lines saying "Unable to locate daemon control file" and this "Stashed password" message which is also informational only.  I just dont know where to start...  Seems that GDM is the problem..  No   ?  Re-install GDM  45.2  ?  If so How to do that  ?  Thanks again for your help.  Brgds.
